# How do I assign a value inside list comprehension

Tags: python

I write a small program using comprehension list python and I need to assign a value to dictionary.

It gives me syntax error.

```
all_freq = {}
Input = 'google.com'
[all_freq[s] += 1 if s in Input  else  all_freq[s] = 1 for s in Input]
```

It says "[" was not closed.

Could you please help me.

Comment: You should not do that, use a regular `for` loop.

Comment: Can you just use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) here?

Comment: its not a good practice, simply do a for loop

Comment: List comprehensions are for defining lists, not for replacing arbitrary `for` loops with one-liners.

Comment: @thomask,  It is not good practise..I need to do with normal for loop

Comment: You also want to check if `s` is in `all_freq`; `s` is in `Input` by definition.

Comment: [all_freq[s] += 1 if s  is in Input  else  all_freq[s] = 1 for s in Input]....Is that you mean? @chepner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just inspired by earlier post, you can also do this way:

Of course, *Counter* is the best to do quick tallying.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

all_freq = defaultdict(int)        # initialize the dict to take 0, if key is not existing yet

for s in 'google':                 # each for-loop, just increment the *count* for corresponding letter
    all_freq[s] += 1

print(all_freq)
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'g': 2, 'o': 2, 'l': 1, 'e': 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a normal `for` loop, not a list comprehension, as you are not trying to create a list of anything.

```
all_freq = {}
for s in Input:
    if s in all_freq:
        all_freq[s] += 1
    else:
        all_freq[s] = 1
```

which can be simplified slightly to

```
all_freq = {}
for s in Input:
    if s not in all_freq:
        all_freq[s] = 0
    all_freq[s] += 1
```

which can be replaced entirely with

```
from collections import Counter
all_freq = Counter(Input)
```

Comment: okye, thanks...Just for my understanding assign a value inside  list comprehension not possible...like = operator doesn't work...am I correct

Comment: Correct. Assignments with `=`, `+=`, etc,  are *statements*, not expressions, and you need expressions inside a list comprehension. (We won't get into assignment expressions using `:=` here.)